# Casting WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to an object

Tags: c#, casting, webmatrix

Is there a way to convert WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to an object. I have code which executes sql query as

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> ExecuteSelectQuery(string query, params object[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<dynamic> resultSets = null;
            OpenStore();
            try
            {
                resultSets = db.Query(query, args);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Unable to execute statement: " + query + ", Failed with error:" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                CloseStore();
            }
            return resultSets;
        }
```

Now if I call this function as

```
string selectQuery = " SELECT * FROM " + TABLENAME + " WHERE condition = @0 ";
 IEnumerable<dynamic> records= (IEnumerable<dynamic>)dbInstance.ExecuteSelectQuery(selectQuery, cond);

for (int i = 0; i < records.Count(); ++i){
      MyObject obj = (MyOject)records.ElementAt(i);
    //do somethinng
    }
```

Here casting WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord (records.ElementAt(i)) to MyObject is giving exception.
Is there a way to convert WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord to MyObject?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a robust way.   I recommend you have the constructor for myObject take a dynamic record.  Then in the loop:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject( records.ElementAt(i) );
```

In the constructor for My Object

```
public MyObject( dynamic r)
{
   a = r.a;
   b = r.b;
   // ...

 }
```

where a is a member of the class and r.a obviously has come from the row in the database.  While this is tedious, it will work.  Perhaps there are defaults or error checking or handling nulls that are also appropriate in the constructor.